# How to pass queryset data with multiple relationships to a template in Django

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates, django-views

I am working on a project with models that have a multiple `OneToOne` and `OneToMany` relationship. The main model, `Listing`, has 4 other models referring to it with a `OneToOne` model depending on the type. The other model `ListingImages` model has a `OneToMany` relationship with the `Listing` model. So, I want to pass data from the `Listing` model and any other related data from the `ListingImages` and the other 4 models as may be necessary to the template. To make this clearly understood here is the code from attached:

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from location_field.models.plain import PlainLocationField
from PIL import Image
from slugify import slugify
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from listing_admin_data.models import (Service, SubscriptionType, PropertySubCategory,
        PropertyFeatures, VehicleModel, VehicleBodyType, VehicleFuelType,
        VehicleColour, VehicleFeatures, BusinessAmenities, Currency
    )


def current_year():
    return datetime.date.today().year

def max_value_current_year(value):
    return MaxValueValidator(current_year())(value)


class Listing(models.Model):
    listing_type_choices = [('P', 'Property'), ('V', 'Vehicle'), ('B', 'Business/Service'), ('E', 'Events')]

    listing_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    listing_type = models.CharField(choices=listing_type_choices, max_length=1, default='P')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    location = PlainLocationField(based_fields=['city'], zoom=7, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    expires_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, null=True, blank=True
    )
    listing_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='list_owner'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.listing_title


def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
    title = instance.listing.listing_title
    slug = slugify(title)
    return "listings_pics/%s-%s" % (slug, filename)


class ListingImages(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename,
                              verbose_name='Listing Images')
    main_image = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Listing Images"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.listing.listing_title} Image'


class Subscriptions(models.Model):
    subscription_type = models.ForeignKey(SubscriptionType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subscription_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    subscription_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    subscribed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    listing_subscription = models.ManyToManyField(Listing)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Subscriptions"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.listing.listing_title} Subscription'


class Property(models.Model):
    sale_hire_choices = [('S', 'Sale'), ('R', 'Rent')]
    fully_furnished_choices = [('Y', 'Yes'), ('N', 'No')]

    listing = models.OneToOneField(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(PropertySubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    for_sale_rent = models.CharField(choices=sale_hire_choices, max_length=1, default=None)
    bedrooms = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    bathrooms = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    rooms = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    land_size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available_from = models.DateField()
    car_spaces = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    fully_furnished = models.CharField(choices=fully_furnished_choices, max_length=1, default=None)
    desc = models.TextField()
    property_features = models.ManyToManyField(PropertyFeatures)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Properties"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.listing.listing_title}'


class Vehicle(models.Model):
    sale_hire_choices = [('S', 'Sale'), ('H', 'Hire')]
    transmission_choices = [('A', 'Automatic'), ('M', 'Manual')]
    drive_choices = [('L', 'Left'), ('R', 'Right')]
    condition_choices = [('L', 'Locally Used'), ('F', 'Foreign Used'), ('N', 'Brand New')]
    interior_choices = [('C', 'Cloth'), ('L', 'Leather'), ('O', 'Other')]

    listing = models.OneToOneField(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    for_sale_hire = models.CharField(choices=sale_hire_choices, max_length=1, default=None)
    # year_of_manufacture = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    year_of_manufacture = models.IntegerField(_('year'), validators=[MinValueValidator(1900), max_value_current_year])
    engine_capacity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    model = models.ForeignKey(VehicleModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
    transmission = models.CharField(choices=transmission_choices, max_length=1, default=None)
    drive = models.CharField(choices=drive_choices, max_length=1, default=None)
    current_millage = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    condition = models.CharField(choices=condition_choices, max_length=1, default=None)
    interior = models.CharField(choices=interior_choices, max_length=1, default=None)
    number_of_doors = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    body_type = models.ForeignKey(VehicleBodyType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fuel_type = models.ForeignKey(VehicleFuelType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    colour = models.ForeignKey(VehicleColour, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vehicle_features = models.ManyToManyField(VehicleFeatures)
    asking_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.listing.listing_title}'


class Business(models.Model):
    listing = models.OneToOneField(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    desc = models.TextField()
    website_address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    business_amenities = models.ManyToManyField(BusinessAmenities)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Businesses"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.listing.listing_title}'
```

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from listings.models import Listing

def index(request):
    listings = Listing.objects.filter(status=True).prefetch_related("listingimages_set").all()
    context = {
        'listing': [
            {
                'title': listing.listing_title,
                'listing_type': listing.listing_type,
                'featured': listing.featured,
                'city': listing.city,
                'images': list(listing.listingimages_set.all()),
            } for listing in listings
        ]
    }

    return render(request, 'base/index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
<!--Featured listings section start-->
<div class="property-section section pt-100 pt-lg-80 pt-md-70 pt-sm-60 pt-xs-50 pb-60 pb-lg-40 pb-md-30 pb-sm-20 pb-xs-10">
    <div class="container">

        <!--Section Title start-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-60 mb-xs-30">
                <div class="section-title center">
                    <h1>New Listings</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Section Title end-->

        <div class="row">

            {% for listing in listings %}
                {% if listing.listing_type == 'P' %}
                    <!--Listing start-->
                    <div class="property-item col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 mb-40">
                        <div class="property-inner">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="single-properties.html"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/property/property-1.jpg' %}" alt=""></a>
                                <ul class="property-feature">
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="area"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/area.png' %}" alt="">{{ listing.property.land_size }} SqFt</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="bed"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/bed.png' %}" alt="">{{ listing.property.bedrooms }}</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="bath"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/bath.png' %}" alt="">{{ listing.property.bathrooms }}</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="parking"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/parking.png' %}" alt="">{{ listing.property.car_spaces }}</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="left">
                                    <h3 class="title"><a href="single-properties.html">{{ listing.title }}</a></h3>
                                    <span class="location"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/marker.png' %}" alt="">{{ listing.city }}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="right">
                                    <div class="type-wrap">
                                        <span class="price">Kshs {{ listing.property.price }}</span>
                                        <span class="type">{{ listing.property.get_for_sale_rent_display }}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Listing end-->
                {% elif listing.listing_type == 'V' %}
                    <!--Listing start-->
                    <div class="property-item col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 mb-40">
                        <div class="property-inner">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="single-properties.html"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/property/property-1.jpg' %}" alt=""></a>
                                <ul class="property-feature">
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="area"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/area.png' %}" alt="">550 SqFt</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="bed"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/bed.png' %}" alt="">6</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="bath"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/bath.png' %}" alt="">4</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="parking"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/parking.png' %}" alt="">3</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="left">
                                    <h3 class="title"><a href="single-properties.html">{{ listing.listing_title }}</a></h3>
                                    <span class="location"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/marker.png' %}" alt="">{{ listing.city }}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="right">
                                    <div class="type-wrap">
                                        <span class="price">$550<span>M</span></span>
                                        <span class="type">For Rent</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Listing end-->
                {% elif listing.listing_type == 'B' %}
                    <!--Listing start-->
                    <div class="property-item col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 mb-40">
                        <div class="property-inner">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="single-properties.html"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/property/property-1.jpg' %}" alt=""></a>
                                <ul class="property-feature">
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="area"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/area.png' %}" alt="">550 SqFt</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="bed"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/bed.png' %}" alt="">6</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="bath"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/bath.png' %}" alt="">4</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="parking"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/parking.png' %}" alt="">3</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="left">
                                    <h3 class="title"><a href="single-properties.html">{{ listing.listing_title }}</a></h3>
                                    <span class="location"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/marker.png' %}" alt="">{{ listing.city }}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="right">
                                    <div class="type-wrap">
                                        <span class="price">$550<span>M</span></span>
                                        <span class="type">For Rent</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Listing end-->
                {% elif listing.listing_type == 'E' %}
                    <!--Listing start-->
                    <div class="property-item col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 mb-40">
                        <div class="property-inner">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="single-properties.html"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/property/property-1.jpg' %}" alt=""></a>
                                <ul class="property-feature">
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="area"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/area.png' %}" alt="">550 SqFt</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="bed"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/bed.png' %}" alt="">6</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="bath"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/bath.png' %}" alt="">4</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="parking"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/parking.png' %}" alt="">3</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="left">
                                    <h3 class="title"><a href="single-properties.html">{{ listing.listing_title }}</a></h3>
                                    <span class="location"><img src="{% static 'base/assets/images/icons/marker.png' %}" alt="">{{ listing.city }}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="right">
                                    <div class="type-wrap">
                                        <span class="price">$550<span>M</span></span>
                                        <span class="type">For Rent</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Listing end-->
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!--Featured listings section end-->
```

For this, a `Listing` can either be a `Property`, a `Vehicle`, a `Business`, or an `Event`. Each `Listing` has several images, but for this case, I want to only pass a single image that is retrieved first from the database.

My main problem is in the context part. I could only get the `Listing` instance and get the other details of the other models from the templates, but from researching, I found out that it is not recommended practice in Django. So how to get the `Listing` details, be it `Property`, `Vehicle`, `Business` or an `Event` and get a `single image` and pass it to the template via a dictionary is where I am getting really confused.

I have tried using the shown code, but I am getting trouble in incorporating the other data from the `Property`, `Vehicle`, `Business` and `Event` and getting a single image.

Comment: I could be missing something but why are you doing that? You can simply do `context = {'listings': listings}` and that's it. Then you iterate through that list like you're already doing on your template. Whatever is inside a Listing instance you'll have access to it.

Comment: @Higor, and how will I get images from the template using your approach?

Comment: The same way you've done in your view but now on the template. `listing.listingimages_set.all` Basically you'll look over those

Comment: Is this the proper way of doing it in Django? Does it have any effects with a large database data?

Comment: Hmm By reading your code again you have a lot of if/elses on the template. Do you know what type you'd get in your view? If so, you can filter overt here

Comment: Okay, I think now I got it working well.

Answer (score 0):

From @Higor suggestion, this is what I did to the view.py:

```
context = {
    'listings': Listing.objects.filter(status=True).order_by('-created_at').prefetch_related("listingimages_set")
}
return render(request, 'base/index.html', context)
```

Then in the template, I went ahead to access the details by:

```
{% for listing in listings %}
    {% if listing.listing_type == 'P' %}
        {{ listing.listingimages_set.first.image_url.url }} #accessing a single image
        {{ listing.listing_title }}
        {{ listing.property.land_size }}
    {% elif listing.listing_type == 'V' %}
        ....
    {% elif listing.listing_type == 'B' %}
        ....
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This made even more neatier, and by using the `first` while accessing the list of images saved me a lot.